# when i will run this query it will give an error

Tags: mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'specific) VALUES ('5.jpg','kids','anyone')' at line 1,,

My query is

```
$sql="INSERT INTO imagetable(image,name,specific) VALUES ('$dbimage','$dbname','dbspec')";
```

Answer (score 1):

`specific` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Either use backticks to escape it or use another name for your column.

```
INSERT INTO imagetable (image, name, `specific`) 
VALUES ('$dbimage','$dbname','dbspec')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sql="INSERT INTO `imagetable` (`image`,`name`,`specific`) VALUES ('$dbimage','$dbname','dbspec')";
```

While not required, it is a good practice to surround your column names (and table names) with ` characters. This avoids issues with reserved words used by the SQL language.

The reason you are getting this issue is because "specific" is a reserved keyword by the SQL language. Think of it like trying to name a variable "if". Since the keyword "if" is reserved by the coding language, you cannot do this. It is the same concept with "specific" in SQL.